# Table layout cutting out 4th column on android app

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am tried to creating a simple calculate app for android. I used a table layout and add 4 rows and 4 columns. In each column I add a button . My problem is the 4th column cuts out as shown in the image below,
[image]

Here is my code below

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.tashtoons.calculator.Calculator">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="false">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="343dp"
            android:layout_height="77dp"
            android:id="@+id/answerScreen"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="371dp"
            android:shrinkColumns="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:baselineAligned="true">


            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <Button
                    android:text="1"
                    android:id="@+id/button"

                    android:layout_column="0"

                    android:width="5px" />

                <Button


                    android:text="2"
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:width="5px" />

                <Button


                    android:text="3"
                    android:id="@+id/button3"
                    android:layout_column="2"
                    android:width="5px" />

                <Button


                    android:text="+"
                    android:id="@+id/button4"
                    android:layout_column="3"
                    android:width="5px" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <Button

                    android:text="4"
                    android:id="@+id/button5"
                    android:layout_column="0"

                    android:width="5px" />

                <Button


                    android:text="4"
                    android:id="@+id/button6"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:width="5px" />

                <Button


                    android:text="5"
                    android:id="@+id/button7"
                    android:layout_column="2"
                    android:width="5px" />

                <Button


                    android:text="-"
                    android:id="@+id/button8"
                    android:layout_column="3"
                    android:width="5px" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <Button

                    android:text="6"
                    android:id="@+id/button9"
                    android:layout_column="0"

                    android:width="5px" />

                <Button


                    android:text="7"
                    android:id="@+id/button10"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:width="5px" />

                <Button


                    android:text="8"
                    android:id="@+id/button11"
                    android:layout_column="2"
                    android:width="5px" />

                <Button


                    android:text="X"
                    android:id="@+id/button12"
                    android:layout_column="3"
                    android:width="5px" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <Button

                    android:text="9"
                    android:id="@+id/button13"
                    android:layout_column="0"

                    android:width="5px" />

                <Button


                    android:text="0"
                    android:id="@+id/button14"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:width="5px" />

                <Button


                    android:text="%"
                    android:id="@+id/button15"
                    android:layout_column="2"
                    android:width="5px" />

                <Button


                    android:text="/"
                    android:id="@+id/button16"
                    android:layout_column="3"
                    android:width="5px" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

How can I stop it from cutting out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of your code Use below code.

Whenever you have to give `same width` of all `Button` or `TextView` or etc. 
There is property of `LinearLayout` is `WeightSum` . This can equal divided the part.

so change your xml code to below format.

**xml code :**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.softeng.xxy.ThirdActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/firstRow">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="4">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="1" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="2" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="3" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="+" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/secondRow"
        android:layout_below="@+id/firstRow">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="4">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="4" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="4" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="5" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="-" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/thirdRow"
        android:layout_below="@+id/secondRow">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="4">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="6" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="7" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="8" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="X" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/forthRow"
        android:layout_below="@+id/thirdRow">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="4">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="9" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="0" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="%" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="/" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Output :**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this it may be help to you

Use

`android:layout_width="match_parent"`

in your `TableLayout`

instead of

`android:layout_width="371dp"`

Answer (score 0):

Where a view has weight = 1 you should set the layout_width to be 0dp to make them have an even amount or space on your screen